# 2 password fields differ in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, types, passwords, field

In my `UserEditType.php`:

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\User;

class UserEditType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user=$user;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName','text',array('data'=>$this->user->getFirstName()))
            ->add('lastName','text',array('data'=>$this->user->getLastName()))
            ->add('email','email',array('data'=>$this->user->getEmail()))
            ->add('dateOfBirth','date',array(
                'data'=>$this->user->getDateOfBirth(),
                'years' => range(date('Y') -100, date('Y')-5)))
            ->add('phone','text',array('data'=>$this->user->getPhone()))
            ->add('password','repeated',array(
                'type'=>'password',
                'invalid_message'=>'Password fields must match',
                'options'=>array('attr'=>array('class'=>'password-field')),
                'required'=>true,
                'first_options'=>array('label'=>'Password'),
                'second_options'=>array('label'=>'Confirm password'),
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>"HearWeGo\\HearWeGoBundle\\Entity\\User"));

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_edit';
    }



}
?>
```

In `profile.html.twig` view:

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>User Profile</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/css/profile.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="toppage">
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/images/banner.png') }}" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/images/personal/profile.png') }}" style="height:40px">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/images/personal/avatar.png') }}" style="width:300px;margin-top: 10px">
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                <h4>{{ form.firstName.vars.data }} {{ form.lastName.vars.data }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left">
                <h5>First Name</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.firstName,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                <h5>Second Name</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.lastName,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                <h5>Email</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.email,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                <h5>Phone</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.phone,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                <h5>Date of Birth</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.dateOfBirth) }}
                <h5>Password</h5>
                {{ form_widget(form.password.first,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.password.second,{'attr':{'size':'40'}}) }}
                <br><br>
                {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
                <br><br>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/images/personal/purchase.png') }}" style="height:40px">
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

In controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/profile",name="edit_profile")
     */
    public function editProfile(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
            return  new Response('Please login');
        }

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

        $user=$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $form=$this->createForm(new UserEditType($user),$user,array('method'=>'POST','action'=>$this->generateUrl('edit_profile')));
        $form->add('submit','submit',array(
            'label'=>'',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'my-custom-button')
        ));
        if ($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->render('@HearWeGoHearWeGo/Default/profile.html.twig',array("form"=>$form->createView()));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@HearWeGoHearWeGo/Default/profile.html.twig',array("form"=>$form->createView()));
    }
```

As I searched, the "repeated" Field Type creates two identical fields whose values must match. This view I created is for user to edit their profile, and they can change password, too. I want to use first password field to type the password they want to change into, and the second one is for confirmation. Is there any way?

Comment: at first glance, this should work. what error are you getting ?

Comment: This code does not get any errors. I just want to say that repeated type is used for 2 identical fields with matched values. I show the code so that I need some help to fix it, so that I can use 2 password fields with different values, not identical values, the first to change password, the second to confirm changes

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't understand that. You can't use a repeated field to do that. Both values must match in this type of field.

Comment: So I ask if there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is to add a simple password field in your form for security reason. The user that wants to modify its password must provide the old one.
And then you add a repeated password field so the user can type his new password (repeated field also for security reason, so the user doesn't make a typo). You could skip that though, and only put a simple password field for the new password as well.

To sum up, you need two different fields in your form. One for the old password, and one for the new (repeated or simple, as you wish).

Comment: I create a Form Type, which is attached with an Entity, my User entity only has one password field, I can't add 2 separate password fields because the second password field does not exist in Entity

Comment: yes you can, just add the parameter "mapped" => false, like this
`->add('oldPassword', 'password', array("mapped" => false));` don't forget to check that this field matches the current password of the user